# Parsing and CABAC Decoder Module

Tags: decode, video-processing, codec, video-codecs, hevc

Can anybody help me with Parsing & CABAC decoding engine design for HEVC. I have googled it but not getting the exact thing.

Comment: In CABAC I am not getting the meanings of the variables used

Comment: @Vitor Can you help me with this or give me some links to its tutorials

Comment: Sorry. Don't know about this subject.

Comment: The main sw-repository is available from https://hevc.hhi.fraunhofer.de/svn/svn_HEVCSoftware/ In there you have everything you need. Compile it for linux/windows and step into the code. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: The CABAC is pretty much the CABAC from H.264 albeit improved. Wikipedia has a nice introduction to CABAC, this document by the mighty Thomas Wiegand explans in more depth http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/820/li/material/source/papers/CABAC.pdf

Comment: @FredrikPihl I have to write Parsing and CABAC decoding engine OF HEVC  in C